# Copy the content of one collection to another using a generic function

Tags: c#, generics

Say I have two collections viz List<PersonOld> and List<PersonNew> as under.

```
private List<PersonOld> GetOldPersonRecord()
{
            var sourceList = new List<PersonOld>();
            for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
                sourceList.Add(new PersonOld { PersonId = i, PersonName = "Name" + i.ToString() });
            return sourceList;
}
```

The need is to fill the List<PersonNew> with the value of List<PersonOld>.

And it needs to be generic ..means given any source collection and destination to the utility function, it needs to fill the destination collection from source.

I am trying

```
public List<T2> Fill<T1, T2>(List<T1> Source, List<T2> Destination)
    {

        Type type1 = typeof(T1);
        var type1List = type1.GetProperties();

        Type type2 = typeof(T2);
        var type2List = type2.GetProperties();


        //determine the underlying type the List<> contains
        Type elementType = type1.GetGenericArguments()[0]; 
        foreach (object record in Source)
        {
            int i = 0;
            object[] fieldValues = new object[Destination.Count];

            foreach (PropertyInfo prop in Destination)
            {
                MemberInfo mi = elementType.GetMember(prop.Name)[0];
                if (mi.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property)
                {
                    PropertyInfo pi = mi as PropertyInfo;
                    fieldValues[i] = pi.GetValue(record, null);
                }
                else if (mi.MemberType == MemberTypes.Field)
                {
                    FieldInfo fi = mi as FieldInfo;
                    fieldValues[i] = fi.GetValue(record);
                }
                i++;
            }
            //Destination..Add(fieldValues);
        }           
    }
```

and invocation

```
var source = GetOldPersonRecord();
var result = Utility.Fill(source, new List<PersonNew>());
```

But no luck..please help

The entities are as under

**PersonNew**

```
public class PersonNew
{
        public int PersonId { get; set; }
        public string PersonName { get; set; }
}
```

**PersonOld**

```
public class PersonOld
{
        public int PersonId { get; set; }
        public string PersonName { get; set; }
}
```

I might have to use reflection...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is using "dynamic" a viable option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a working example:

The main piece is the CreateMapping method, which just provides a delegate for converting from one type to another.  Once you have that, copying source objects into a list of destination objects becomes trivial, as shown further below in my Fill method.

```
    public static Func<T1, T2> CreateMapping<T1, T2>()
        where T2 : new()
    {
        var typeOfSource = typeof(T1);
        var typeOfDestination = typeof(T2);

        // use reflection to get a list of the properties on the source and destination types
        var sourceProperties = typeOfSource.GetProperties();
        var destinationProperties = typeOfDestination.GetProperties();

        // join the source properties with the destination properties based on name
        var properties = from sourceProperty in sourceProperties
                         join destinationProperty in destinationProperties
                         on sourceProperty.Name equals destinationProperty.Name
                         select new { SourceProperty = sourceProperty, DestinationProperty = destinationProperty };

        return (x) =>
        {
            var y = new T2();

            foreach (var property in properties)
            {
                var value = property.SourceProperty.GetValue(x, null);
                property.DestinationProperty.SetValue(y, value, null);
            }

            return y;
        };
    }

    public static void Fill<T1, T2>(List<T1> Source, List<T2> Destination)
        where T2 : new()
    {
        Destination.AddRange(Source.Select(CreateMapping<T1, T2>()));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You may take a look at [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/).

---

As far as your utility method is concerned you must declare the generic arguments:

```
public class Utility
{
    public static List<T2> Fill<T1, T2>(List<T1> Source, List<T2> Destination)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: asking for TeamCity username and pwd

Comment: @user1025901, you could install it through the NuGet package: `Install-Package AutoMapper` or download from GitHub: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/downloads

Comment: That's fine...if i want to do it by myself programatically, can you please give the initial guidance...the utility function declaration is giving some problem

Comment: @user1025901, you want to do what by yourself? You don't want to use AutoMapper?

Comment: Error: The type or namespace name 'T2' could not be found..The type or namespace name 'T1' could not be found

Comment: It is a great tool..just tested but i need to have the source code too..since it is not available , so i am thinking of doing it by myself

Comment: @user1025901, you haven't declared any generic argument for your Fill method and yet you are trying to use them. I have updated my example to show how to fix this error. But if you decide to use AutoMapper a I suggested you don't need any utility method at all because AutoMapper already provides you with the `Mapper.Map<TSource, TDestination>` method that does exactly that.

Comment: @user1025901, AutoMapper is open source: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper What exactly is not available to you?

Comment: Hi , I have updated my answer ..but still i am not yet reached to the solution..could you please help a bit..

Answer (score 0):

If using reflection, iterate through the source collection, instantiating instances of the target class. Insert these into a newly created list.

Next, Use GetProperties on the source type to get a collection of PropertyInfo classes. Iterate through these, picking out the name of each, and use Type.GetProperty to see if there is a property of the same name on the destination class. If so, use PropertyInfo.SetValue to set the value on each target object.

NB Need to do a bit more work if the properties are reference types - you'd need to consider whether you want to copy those types, or copy the reference

If the objects are identical, An alternative would be to serialise to and from XML.

Comment: Trying like this public List<T2> Fill<T1, T2>(List<T1> Source, List<T2> Destination)
        {

            Type type1 = typeof(T1);
            var type1List = type1.GetProperties();

            Type type2 = typeof(T2);
            var type2List = type2.GetProperties();

            foreach (PropertyInfo prop in type1List)
            {
                var name = prop.Name;

            }           
        } .. could you please help

Comment: Hi , I have updated my answer ..but still i am not yet reached to the solution..could you please help a bit..